# A function, adding something within a function, but printing it outside

Tags: python

So i'm stuck with this problem, how can i add something within a function and print it from out of the function

```
import random 

def dieRoll():
  sum = 0
  for i in range (die-1):
    dieThrow = random.randrange( 1, sides+1)
    sum += dieThrow
    print(dieThrow)
  print("That totals: ", sum)
  return i

players = int(input("How many players are rolling dice? "))
die = int(input("How many dice does each player roll? "))
sides = int(input("How many sides does each die have? "))

for a in range(1, players+1):
  print("Player",a, "rolled: ")
  print(dieRoll())
```

it's supposed to look something like:

```
Player 1 rolled:
5
4
9
that totals: 18
```

but i'm getting something like:

```
Player 1 rolled:
5
4
that totals: 9
9
```

i feel like the answer is right in front of me but i just can't see it

Comment: Don't print whatever `dieRoll` returns

Comment: it looks like `die` is set to 2, you subtract 1, that leaves `for i in range(1)`, which means the loop gets executed twice, the result is printed and then you print it again. Remove the final print statement from the function, call it like `print("That totals: ",dieRoll())` (or remove the `print()` around `dieRoll`) and pass it `3` instead of `2`.

Comment: Since this asks two separate questions, I had to vote to close this as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you print what the function return in the end, if you want such output you have two choices :

```
print(i)
return("That totals: ", sum)
```

or the other choice :

```
print(i)
print("That totals: ", sum)
#replace print(dieRoll())
dieRoll()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
for i in range (die-1):
```

Try this instead:

```
for i in range(0, die):
```

The thing is, the range function by default starts at **0** and "stops" when it gets to the last number (does not execute it), meaning you are not geting to do  that last dice roll you expected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `range(die)`, no need for `0`.

Comment: *Explicit is better than implicit.*

Comment: _Although practicality beats purity._ There's no need to specify a 0 base because it is the standard assumption in the IT.

Comment: Not writing 2 characters is by far not practicality.